# Prevent image hotlinking; only allow referer and redirected requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have some images in a bucket on S3. My app uses these images. What I want is the following:

- Only allow the image to be accessed if:

  1. The referer is my site - *This I can already do with a bucket policy*
  2. The user was redirected from my site

The problem is the redirect here, because, when redirected, no referer is sent to Amazon S3.

Is there a way to limit access to my S3 files in the way I described above?

My current bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "e9c9be4d-cdfc-470c-8582-1d5a9e4d04be",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://myapp.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some info on the bucket policy (it is interesting in itself)

Comment: Added my current bucket policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Have your files be private.
- Use signed URLs in the links/redirects to your images.

  - The signed URLs include an expiration; Amazon will not show your image past the expiration.
  - The signed URLs cannot be forged; Amazon will not show your image if the signature is missing or invalid.

Comment: Signed URLs might be the best solution here indeed. I'm going to look further into it.

Comment: It turns out this works perfectly! I give users a URL that's only valid for 10 seconds (enough to load the image in their browsers).

Comment: You may want 10 minutes. It can take way more than 10 seconds to load a webpage, depending on where you are or what network you are connecting from (suppose you are loading the webpage on a phone). But even 10 minutes effectively makes it impossible for anyone else to use your images.

Comment: true. I've set it at 10 seconds to see it work. I'll have to determine a better value later by observing users etc. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

This guy appears to have solved the problem:

http://www.powercram.com/2010/07/s3-bucket-policy-to-restrict-access-by.html

Comment: This is actually about blocking specific referrers.